# How to return a type parameter that is a subtype of an Array?

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, covariance, contravariance

I don't understand why this code is impossible in Scala:

```
  def getColumns[T <: Array[_]] ():Array[(String,T)] ={
     Array(Tuple2("test",Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)))
  }
```

Compiler says:

> Expression of type Array[(String,Array[Double])] doesn't conform to expected type Array[(String, T)]

I have the same error with this code:

```
 def getColumns[T <: Array[Double]] ():Array[(String,T)] ={
     Array(Tuple2("test",Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)))
  }
```

It's more clear with my complete use case, finally I have chosen an `Array[AnyVal]`:

```
class SystemError(message: String, nestedException: Throwable) extends Exception(message, nestedException) {
  def this() = this("", null)
  def this(message: String) = this(message, null)
  def this(nestedException : Throwable) = this("", nestedException)
}

class FileDataSource(path:String) {
   val fileCatch = catching(classOf[FileNotFoundException], classOf[IOException]).withApply(e => throw new SystemError(e))

   def getStream():Option[BufferedSource]={
     fileCatch.opt{Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream(path))}
   }
}

class CSVReader(src:FileDataSource) {

  def lines= src.getStream().get
  val head = lines.getLines.take(1).toList(0).split(",")
  val otherLines = lines.getLines.drop(1).toList

  def getColumns():Array[(String,Array[_])] ={
    val transposeLines = otherLines.map { l => l.split(",").map {
      d => d match {
        case String => d
        case Int => d.toInt
        case Double => d.toDouble
      }}.transpose }

    head zip transposeLines.map {_.toArray}
  }
}
```

Can you give me some explanation or good links to understand the issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your function must be able to work with any `T` (any array type), however, it will always return an `Array[(String,Array[Double])]`.

A simpler working signature would be:

```
def getColumns[T](): Array[(String,Array[T])]
```

But in the body of the function you will have to create an array of type `T`.

Comment: Hum, perhaps my example is silly, in reality getColumns can return other array type, Int or Double, so perhaps my approach is not good here or there a solution  ?

Comment: finally, i complete with my real use case and the solution i choose in this case

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature requires a `T` in the compound return type, but you give it a `Array[Double]`. Note that `T <: Array[Double]`, not the other way around. The following code works:

```
def getColumns[T >: Array[Double]] ():Array[(String,T)] ={
 Array(Tuple2("test",Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)))
}
```

Shouldn't be what you want but just for elaborating the problem.